# Find the element in a list of triples which has z-coordinate nearest a specified value

Tags: list-manipulation, nearest

Here is my list coordinate `{x,y,z}`

```
list  = {{30.8179, -62.2833, -155.032}, {33.1172, -61.0918, -156.656},
         {35.3704, -59.8155, -158.28}, {37.5745, -58.456, -159.904},
         {39.7264, -57.0155, -161.528}, {41.8232, -55.4957, -163.152},
         {43.8619, -53.8989, -164.776}, {45.8397, -52.2272, -166.4}}
```

If I only knew the value of z coordinate only, e.g. `162.4`
How to make programming in order to detect the nearest position or index with z value of `162.4`?

Comment: You've looked up `Nearest[]`, no?

Comment: Since the z-coordinates in your example data are all negative, I suspect you meant you want the triple having `z` closest to -164.4. Is that right?

Comment: You mean `-162.4` right?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you want to find the element of `list` that is nearest to `z = -162.4`, it can be done like so:

```
Extract[list, Nearest[list[[All, 3]] -> "Index", -162.4]]
```

> `{41.8232, -55.4957, -163.152}`

Comment: I've apply it in version 10.3 but it's not worked. Is there any additional code?

Comment: @Self, try `Extract[list, Nearest[list[[All, 3]] -> Automatic, -162.4]]`.

Comment: Yeah, It works.

Answer (score 7):

To get the vector with the most similar z value:

```
Nearest[Last /@ list -> list, 162.4]
(* Out: {{30.8179, -62.2833, -155.032}} *)
```

To get the index of the same vector:

```
Nearest[Last /@ list -> Automatic, 162.4]
(* Out: {1} *)
```